# Bundle multiple vendor files together by defining the files to bundle with WebPack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

How can you bundle multiple .min.js vendor files together with WebPack 2?
I'm starting with webpack and mostly one entry file is used to bundle everything together.

I just want the same behavior as the ASP.NET optimization bundling or the new ASP.NET core bundling with the bundleconfig.json file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification

The project will contain multiple different bundles.

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple entries and within one entry you can pass an array. This way the files will be bundled together:

```
entry: {
    one: [
        "./src/a.js",
        "./src/b.js"
    ],
    two: "./src/app.js"        
},
```